# Error 500 on Joomla 2.5.8 : JHtml: :jquery not supported. File not found

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5.8 . Actually after i install a new theme this error occurred "JHtml: :jquery not supported. File not found" . Since i am new on Joomla i was unable to figure out. I even tried out Joomla Jquery Library plugins but non helped. Please help me to sort it out.

**This is the Debug info:**

> ```
> 1 JSite->render() JROOT/index.php:48
> 2 JDocumentHTML->parse()  JROOT/includes/application.php:259
> 3 JDocumentHTML->_fetchTemplate() JROOT/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:414
> 4 JDocumentHTML->_loadTemplate()  JROOT/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:591
> 5 require()   JROOT/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:531
> 6 TemplateWarpHelper->render()    JROOT/templates/yoo_revista/index.php:19
> 7 include()   JROOT/templates/yoo_revista/warp/helpers/template.php:49
> 8 TemplateWarpHelper->render()    JROOT/templates/yoo_revista/layouts/template.php:17
> 9 include()   JROOT/templates/yoo_revista/warp/helpers/template.php:49
> 10 JHtml::_() JROOT/templates/yoo_revista/warp/systems/joomla/layouts/head.php:22
> 11 JError::raiseError()   JROOT/libraries/joomla/html/html.php:123
> 12 JError::raise()    JROOT/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by new theme? Template? If so what is the actual line of code that is producing the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locate the line that the code being used to import jQuery and make sure it shows the following:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Which imports it in noConflict mode, but is also for **Joomla 3.x** only

Else you can replace it with the following, which will detect if a jQuery library is already being loaded and if not, it will import it.

```
if (!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery'))
{
    JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
    JFactory::getDocument()->addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JHtmlJquery is not a class in Joomla! 2.5, it was introduced in 3.0 with the other UI changes.  Odds are the extension you've installed is designed for Joomla! 3.0 and later.