# jhtml jquery in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I can not access my Joomla-based Website.

Due to the following error message:

```
error:500
JHtmlJquery: :framework not found in file
```

I would be appreciated if someone can help with this issue.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891599/error-500-on-joomla-2-5-8-jhtml-jquery-not-supported-file-not-found ?

Answer (score 2):

Verify you are using Joomla! 3.0 and that the file exists at libraries/cms/html/jquery.php.  If you're on 3.0 and missing that file, you have a corrupt site and should reinstall the latest 3.0 package on your site to ensure you have all files.

If you're using Joomla! 2.5 or earlier, you may be using an extension that either isn't compatible with those versions of Joomla! or there is a bug in the code.  Determine what extension you've installed is causing the error and report it to the developer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
JLoader::import( 'joomla.version' );
$version = new JVersion();
if (version_compare( $version->RELEASE, '2.5', '<=')) {
    if (JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery') !== true) {
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery-latest.js");
        JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery', true);
   }
} else {
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing jQuery using Joomla as below

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to enter the administrator end of my joomla 2.5.3 site after installing a module, but I got this error message below:

> 500 - JHtml: jquery not supported. file not found

SOLUTION

The error occurred as a result of installing the wrong version of the module for joomla 3.4.3 instead of for joomla 2.5.3. The new module was incompatible with the site.

I had to go into the cpanel, then entered into the file manager, click on modules, then located the wrong module that was installed, clicked on it and deleted the folder.

I then relogin into the administrator (backend), and I couldn't access the site backend again.

The steps looks so easy, but you have to be really sure of the wrong module installed and if not sure, delete the recently installed module folder

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to solve this problem. You should just copy latest version of the file *jquery.php* from a fresh latest version of joomla, under path *libraries/cms/html/jquery.php* to your joomla *libraries/cms/html/* directory in version 2.5.x or 3.x