# Joomla 2.5.28. Error 500 JHtml: :behavior not supported. File not found

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I'm using a search component (Offlajn Universal AJAX live search) in my Joomla 2.5.28 site. When searching for a word, I get the error:

```
Error 500 JHtml: :behavior not supported. File not found.
```

This is the info I get from debugging.

```
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   JSite->dispatch()   /home/mysite/public_html/index.php:42
2   JComponentHelper::renderComponent() /home/mysite/public_html/includes/application.php:194
3   JComponentHelper::executeComponent()    /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:348
4   require_once()  /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:380
5   JController->execute()  /home/mysite/public_html/components/com_search/search.php:15
6   SearchController->display() /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:761
7   JController->display()  /home/mysite/public_html/components/com_search/controller.php:33
8   SearchViewSearch->display() /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:722
9   JView->display()    /home/mysite/public_html/components/com_search/views/search/view.html.php:195
10  JView->loadTemplate()   /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/t3/includes/joomla25/view.php:205
11  include()   /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/t3/includes/joomla25/view.php:649
12  JHtml::_()  /home/mysite/public_html/plugins/system/t3/base-bs3/html/com_search/search/default.php:11
13  JError::raiseError()    /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html.php:123
14  JError::raise() /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
15  JError::throwError()    /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:176
16  call_user_func_array()  /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:214
17  JError::handleCallback()     
18  call_user_func()    /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:765
19  plgSystemReDJ::customError()
```

If I try going back home and search again, I sometimes get it right (no error).

Can someone help with this?

I tried searching [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891599/error-500-on-joomla-2-5-8-jhtml-jquery-not-supported-file-not-found) but it doesn't seem like mine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you must try the share link added by you.

Comment: Offlajn Universal AJAX live search is a commercial extension, therefore please contact the developer of this extension

Comment: Thanks @Lodder, but my subscription period expired ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the extension code, you will most likely see the following:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

Try replacing the above with this:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.mootools');
```

The first code snippet it used for Joomla 3.x, so you will need to use the second one which is for Joomla 2.5

Comment: Hmm, this must be somewhere in the component code, right?

Comment: I found that line in public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html.php and replaced it accordingly but the error persists.
I guess this isn't the right file

Comment: No, I said within the search extension code, not the core Joomla library. Undo what you have changed in that file

Comment: Ok, undone. I have mod_universal_ajaxlivesearch with folders: cache, classes, engine, helper, images, params, themes. But couldn't find JHtml::_('behavior.framework'); anywhere

Comment: Hmm, well download the module and do a mass find. Search for `JHtml::`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73415/discussion-between-nuno-nogueira-and-lodder).